# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 8 bytes

Tags: php

привет.
Как подавить выбрасывание ошибки "Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 8 bytes..."
Задача у мене в проверке что строка серилизированая через serialize()

```
function isserialized($str){
    try{
        unserialize($str);
        return true;
    }
   catch (Exception $e) {
   return false;
}

}
var_dump(isserialized('notseria'));
```

Также интересует что за `$str === 'b:0;'`

```
$data = @unserialize($str);
if ($str === 'b:0;' || $data !== false) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "not ok";
}
```

Comment: Вот здесь очень здорово парень все объяснил:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152904/unserialize-function-unserialize-error-at-offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще подавление ошибок - плохо, но если уж очень хочется, то что мешает использовать `'@'` перед функцией, как во втором примере?

А по поводу собственно второго примера...

```
$a = false;
echo serialize($a); // результат - как раз строка 'b:0;'
```

В первом методе было подавление ошибки через `@`. Соответственно условие `if ($str === 'b:0;' || $data !== false)` проверяет, удачно ли выполнилась функция `unserialize($str)`.

Comment: Только сразу хочу обратить ваше внимание, что это костыль и так лучше не делать. Корректнее будет обработать ошибку. Например, преобразовать ее в исключение и засунуть это все в `try...catch`

Comment: Спасибо большое.Но я пытался через try...catch но Notice скрыть так не получается...

Comment: `try...catch` ловит только исключения.

Вы можете поступить разными способами. Можно просто отключить вывод Notice сообщений в php.ini (error_reporting), а можете отловить этот Notice, преобразовав эту ошибку в исключение.

[`set_error_handler()`][1] вам в помощь :-)

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php